# android webview can not show content by loaddatawithbaseurl sometime

Tags: android, webview

I use webview to load local html data like this

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("about:blank", finalSrc, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

the **finalSrc** is a variable of html string.

sometimes, the webview can display the corrent content,but sometimes not.

and I found that if I clear the cache of my app, the webview works well again.

so what's wrong with my app?

Comment: can you take a look at log when it doesn't load and share the logs

Comment: @AmodGokhale  there is nothing error information in the logs. when the bug is show,  I set the breakpoint at the onPageFinished() method, it never be called.

Comment: it's difficult to debug without seeing finalSrc content or error logs but can you try changing it to webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, finalSrc, "text/html", "utf-8",null);

Answer (score 0):

rather than using BaseUrl why don't use loadData. for example

`webview.loadData(finalSrc, "text/html", "UTF-8");`